# Remove dashes from datetime

Tags: python, datetime

How do I remove the dashes from the output of this code?

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2014,1,1)

for i in range(50): 
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(date)
```

I would like the output to be:

```
20140102
20140103
20140104
20140105
20140106
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
In [83]: d = datetime.date(2014,1,1)

In [84]: d.strftime("%Y%m%d")
Out[84]: '20140101'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2014,1,1)

for i in range(50): 
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    # Print as a string
    print(str(date).replace("-",""))
    # Print as an integer
    print(int(str(date).replace("-","")))
```